GitLab CI: Liquibase w/ SSH Tunneled Database
I am currently trying to setup a liquibase pipeline in Gitlab (gitlab.com) using their shared runners to manage a database schema. The database is only accessible over SSH though (There is a jump box that sits between the outside world and the database instance) with an SSH key.
The main problem I have at the moment is installing a SSH client within the same job that will be running the liquibase commands to first establish an SSH tunnel so the database can be reached.
I am using the official liquibase docker image and my.gitlab-ci.yml configuration is as follows:
image: liquibase/liquibase:latest

stages:
  - history

variables:
  INSTALL_MYSQL: "true"
  LIQUIBASE_SEARCH_PATH: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR},${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/changelogs,${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/scripts"
  LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_URL: "jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_SCHEMA}"
  LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME: "${DATABASE_USERNAME}"
  LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
  LIQUIBASE_CHANGELOG_FILE: "master_changelog.xml"

history:
  stage: history
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - chmod 400 "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
  script:
    - ssh -f -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 3306:$SSH_SERVER_IP:3306 sleep 10
    - liquibase history

However when running this job, I run into the following error:

Ive tried quite a few ways to install a ssh client whilst using this docker image but my conclusion is that im unable to do this because this liquibase image locks down the user to a non root user which I assume is required to install packages.
Hoping anyone can help advise ways I can actually achieve this?
Extra info:

Gitlab documentation that was followed on ssh keys: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ssh_keys.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor
Official Liquibase docker image that shows non root user: https://github.com/liquibase/docker/blob/13d063767623e282539b232a3a9ed19f4b3d7bbd/Dockerfile

